# How can I prevent camera rolling in Open3D

Tags: python, open3d

I am trying to prevent the scene camera from rolling whilst maintaining pitch and yaw actions. I have built an interactive scene using open3d.visualization.gui and O3DVisualzier. The following code block runs every frame and maintains a fixed 'up' vector - however the camera still rolls while the mouse is dragged, before snapping back to 0 roll. Is there anyway I can run this code before the scene is rendered without having to change source code and build from source? Is there a better way to prevent scene camera rolling?

```
        # Obtain the current view matrix
        view_matrix = np.array(self.main_vis.scene.camera.get_view_matrix())

        # Extract the rotation and translation from the view matrix
        R = view_matrix[:3, :3]
        T = view_matrix[:3, 3]

        # Calculate the camera position ('eye') in world space
        eye = -np.matmul(R.T, T)

        # The direction the camera is looking at is given by the negative Z-axis of the rotation matrix
        # (This assumes a right-handed coordinate system with Y up)
        forward = -R.T @ np.array([0, 0, 1])

        # Calculate the 'center' the camera is looking at
        center = eye + forward

        # Define a 'world up' vector (assuming Y is up)
        world_up = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 0.0]).reshape((3,1))

        # Pass these values into look_at function to update the camera view
        self.main_vis.scene.camera.look_at(center.reshape((3,1)), eye.reshape((3,1)), world_up)
```